# How to create custom editors with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

In some addons, for example Animation Nodes, there is a custom editors which is not in default Blender. How could i use scripting to create a custom editor?

[image]

Comment: *"There is no support for creating editors in Python in 2.8. There was some work towards it, but nothing finished."* from: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/developing-a-new-editor/894/20