# How to create a large persistent window in the middle of the screen

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I have a script that performs a bunch of calculations (specifically: compare the area of meshes with that of the UVs to get the scale factor of said UVs)  and I would like to display the result of the calculations prominently for the user to see.

However all I can find is `bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu` which seems to (a) pop up at the mouse position and (b) vanish after a few secs.

How can I display a large persistent window in the middle of the screen?

Comment: This goes against Blenders UI principles and design guidelines, but I don't think it is possible regardless. If you want it to be permanent why not integrate into a panel in an existing editor, like say the Properties Window, or perhaps the 3D view toolshelf?

Comment: [Defining your own editor in a new window is not possible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185254) other than custom node editors. What type of information do you want to display, textual? If yes then maybe it can be shown in a *Text Editor* in a new window

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Hi! I'm actually open to any solution, my goal is to tell the user "hey, the result of the calculation you asked me to perform is 16". That's all. Right now - with what I know - the user has to squint to see the number, and has to be very fast in catching it

Comment: This type of result information is typically displayed in the status bar running along the bottom, but is usually temporary and will vanish after a few seconds. A more permanent log is kept in the *Info* editor. If it is so important for the user to see this so prominently maybe popup a new window with an info editor, though that sounds cumbersome and unwieldy, also other log information is displayed there